# Срабатывание функции на элементе

Tags: javascript, jquery

Динамически создается элемент. Проблема в последнем событи `.on()`. Консоль срабатывает дважды. Вопрос может и туповат, но я пересмотрел код сто раз и не понимаю почему событие двоится.

Задача: выполнить функцию когда элемент создался, и в функции нужно иметь возможность использовать именно этот элемент через указатель `this`. Может я выбрал не корректный способ это сделать?

```
           $(this)
                .append($('<div>')
                    .addClass('sossage drop')
                    .css({
                        'background-color': plColor,
                        'width': plLength + 'px',
                        'left': (plPosition - $('.playlists').offset().left) - cursorShift
                    })
                    .attr({
                        'id': identifier,
                        'name': plName
                    })
                    .dblclick(function () {
                        var popupPositionY = parseInt($(this).css('top')) - 230  /*popup height + 8px above*/;
                        var popupPositionX = (parseInt($(this).css('left')) - 76 /*middle of popup width*/) + +(parseInt($(this).css('width')) / 2 /*half of playlist width*/);
                        var name = $(this).attr('name');
                        plSausage = this;
                        $('.pl-popup')
                            .show()
                            .css({
                                'top': popupPositionY + 'px',
                                'left': popupPositionX + 'px'
                            });
                        $('.pl-popup .popup_header span')
                            .text('Playlist: ' + name);
                    })
                    .on("DOMNodeInserted", function () {
                        console.log(this);
                    }));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело скорее всего не в коде, просто событие `DOMNodeInserted` устаревшее, оно не срабатывает, а всплывает (может по нескольку раз).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events

Comment: Вот оно что. Спасибо, может быть. Посоветуете замену?

Comment: 2 варианта... 1) завести флаг по которому блокируется повторное срабатывание кода внутри обработчика. 2) Превентивная обработка изменений, т.е. забить на событие и при внесении изменений элемента вызывать функцию.

Comment: если пойти по второму пути, и отслеживать изменение "элемент добавлен", то как ловить `this` кокретно этого элемента?

Comment: Отправлять параметром ...